# dynamically add and remove view in android

Tags: android

I have an activity with a `ScrollView`, then I have to display the list of data using `LinearLayout` which will result in add and remove data dynamically like this:

layout_main.xml:

```
<ScrollView>
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <!-- other views -->

        <!-- data holder -->
        <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></RelativeLayout>

        <!-- other views -->
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

layout_item.xml:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <TextView   android:id="@+id/index"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView   android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then in the codes:

```
RelativeLayout container=findViewById(R.id.container);
private void onDataRequested(List<Data> items){
    container.removeAllViews();
    for(Data d : items){
        LinearLayout ll= (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_item,null);
        ((TextView)ll.findViewById(R.id.index)).setText(d.getIndex()+"");
        ((TextView)ll.findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(d.getName());
        ll.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            .....
        });
        container.addView(ll);
    }
}
```

I wonder if this is the right way or if this will cause any performance problem?

BTW, why I do not use a `ListView` with header and foot instead of the `ScrollView` is in that the other views are not proper to add as header and foot since there are so many these kind of views.

Comment: instead of calling container.addView() see the second param of inflate method (null in your case)